# Template selector in WordPress Page Attributes disappear

Tags: wordpress, editor

[image]

The Page template selector disappear from the Page Attributes Option in the page/post editor. I'm using the last **WordPress** version(5.2.3) and **Divi** editor version(3.29.3). I cleaned up all the caches, but I'm  not able to see that template selector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of time, I found the problem... I'm created a Child theme base on Divi, and for any reason the Page Attribute was not been displayed because the *style.css* file from my child theme was not including this line in the main header comment description:

/*
Theme Name: #####

Theme URI: http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/

Version: 3.29.3

Description: Child Theme from Divi created by ###

Author: Me

Author URI: http://www.###.com

**Template: Divi**

License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

*/

I added the line, recompile the LESS, and the option inside the page/post editor appeared again fortunately.